# How to calculate in python the sum of variables in each unique raw in dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, variables, sum

I have a dataframe with information of different users (ID) with many duplicated categorical variables (photo) and its corresponding numbers of interactions (likes). How i can calculate the sum of total likes for each different photo type?

For example:

```
id    photo_type    likes 
1     nature          2
2     art             4
3     art             1
4     fashion         3
5     fashion         2
```

I expect to get information like that:

```
total numbers of likes for nature:2
total numbers of likes for art: 5
total numbers of likes for fashion: 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`:

```
df.groupby('photo_type')['likes'].sum()
```

Output:

```
photo_type
art        5
fashion    5
nature     2
Name: likes, dtype: int64
```